# URL con arreglos en Angular

Tags: array, url, angular

Es posible enviar una variable que contenga un arreglo de id en una url de un componente a otro en Angular? 
Lo que intento hacer es ir modificando la variable dinamicamente porque no se de inicio cuantos ids enviar y una vez concluyo enviar la variable con el arreglo de ids por la url hacia el otro componente, y luego desde ese otro componente recuperar el arreglo de ids con un `.split` o algo similar.

Imaginemos que ya tenemos la variable con el arreglo de ids

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Necesito enviarla por una url hacia el otro componente y luego recuperarla para poder trabajar con los ids.
Algo como esto: `url_del_sitio/` y ahi seguidamente enviar mi variable `array`

Comment: Tiene que ser necesariamente por url?

Comment: Si, la idea es como dije, enviar por url los ids concatenados ej: `url_del_sitio/ids?id=1&id=2&id=3` y luego recuperar de la url esos ids en otro compoente. Gracias